# How can i draw a point in my QFrame, i want to use qt to do that?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to draw a pixel in my QFrame, i am overwriten my painEvent function like this:

```
void MainBoard::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QFrame::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter painter(this);
    point.paintPoint(event,100,100);
}
```

and my class point have the function

```
class Point: public QWidget
{
public:
    void paintPoint(QPaintEvent *event,  int x, int y)
        {
        QWidget::paintEvent(event);
            QPainter painter(this);
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 12, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
            painter.drawLine(x, y, x+1, y+1);
        }
};
```

it does not working, what is the wrong?

the error is

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `QWidget::paintEvent(event)` on your `Point` object from a context where Qt isn't expecting it -- i.e. from within `MainBoard::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)`.  Typically in Qt you never explicitly call `paintEvent()` on a different widget yourself; rather Qt's event-loop code calls it for you at the appropriate times.

I suggest removing the call to `QWidget::paintEvent(event)` and passing a reference to the `QPainter` in to `paintPoint()` instead of the `QPaintEvent`.  (In fact there isn't really any reason to have `Point` subclass `QWidget` at all if you're just going to use it to draw a point; you could simplify things greatly by just calling `painter.drawLine()`, or better yet `painter.drawPoint()` as necessary directly from `MainBoard::paintEvent()` instead).

Comment: i want to create my own library to put pixel, i am study computer graphics, in the books told me create a Point class

Comment: Creating a Point class is reasonable; making Point a subclass of QWidget is not.